# Abort previous running async componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

We have a component, connected to the redux store, that has this `componentDidMount` definition:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const page = await fetchPage(this.props.page);
  const section = await fetchSection(this.props.section);

  this.props.saveDataToStore({ page, section });
}
```

So, every time the component is mounted, it'll run this code.

Now let's imagine that we go to another section of our app, so the component gets unmounted, and then we come back before the previous `componentDidMount` has finished its execution, mounting the component again and starting fetching new data. Every time the data is fetched, we save it to the redux store.

I think that there is no way to abort previous `componentDidMount` execution to prevent setting old data from previous calls. So, my question is, what's the best approach to follow to prevent old data being set?

I've been able to solve it having a function that does all of these calls (like `fetchData`) that handles an `AbortController` object, but I found it a bit verbose, so do you know what's the recommended approach to follow in this situation?

Comment: Is using hook possible? Then you can use `useEffect` hook as mentioned here to abort saving the data to the redux store. https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#speaking-of-race-conditions

Answer (score 3):

Using the `AbortController` or a library like `axios` that supports cancellable requests is a good solution, but you could also keep an instance variable that you change to `false` when the component unmounts and check against his before you use `setState` after the requests have finished.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = true;

  async componentDidMount() {
    const page = await fetchPage(this.props.page);
    const section = await fetchSection(this.props.section);

    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({ page, section });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with async actions is that you don't certainly know which one will be received first, so you might even receive the response from an old request as the latest and this one will override the state (and the component might be mounted when this happen). Also, imagine that we have to send 6 requests. Will be great to do not even have to send the requests from old `componentDidMount` executions.

Comment: @Emi If the component is unmounted and mounted again, the newly mounted component cannot get the response data from the previously mounted component. You could check `_isMounted` between every `await`, or better yet use cancellable requests in that case.

Comment: We might even need a combination of both? 1. Check if component is mounted (or cancelled by an abort signal) between every `await` (to prevent sending the request) and 2. Send the abort signal to each fetch request that will abort current running request. We should also be able to use the same abort signal in both cases.

Comment: @Emi If your goal is to avoid unnecessary requests too, this becomes really intricate. I'd suggest to take a look at observables, the whole chain is naturally cancelled at once when an observable is unsubscribed, that's one of major benefits of observables over promises.

Comment: Thank you both. BTW, I've updated my question to use redux store instead of component's state. I think it clarifies the issue I was mentioning.